# How to count number of previous events without a groupby

Tags: mysql, count

I have a simple events table with userid and timestamp. Each row is an occurrence of a user performing an event:

```
+--------+---------------+
| userid |   timestamp   |
+--------+---------------+
|      3 | 5/25/14 23:30 |
|      2 | 5/25/14 20:57 |
|      1 | 5/25/14 20:18 |
|      2 | 5/25/14 18:49 |
|      2 | 5/25/14 13:41 |
|      1 | 5/25/14 5:47  |
|      3 | 5/24/14 22:34 |
|      1 | 5/24/14 22:07 |
|      2 | 5/24/14 21:53 |
|      1 | 5/24/14 21:42 |
+--------+---------------+
```

I'd like to add/select a column with a count of how many times I've seen the user previously for EACH row. So the expected output would be:

```
+--------+---------------+-------+
| userid |   timestamp   | count |
+--------+---------------+-------+
|      3 | 5/25/14 23:30 |     2 |
|      2 | 5/25/14 20:57 |     4 |
|      1 | 5/25/14 20:18 |     4 |
|      2 | 5/25/14 18:49 |     3 |
|      2 | 5/25/14 13:41 |     2 |
|      1 | 5/25/14 5:47  |     3 |
|      3 | 5/24/14 22:34 |     1 |
|      1 | 5/24/14 22:07 |     2 |
|      2 | 5/24/14 21:53 |     1 |
|      1 | 5/24/14 21:42 |     1 |
+--------+---------------+-------+
```

For example, the third row from the top says I've seen user 1 a total of four times including the current one.  The bottom row with a count of 1 means I've seen user 1 only once (this is the first time).

Is there a way to do this type of counting in mysql?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT userid, timestamp,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable t2
    WHERE t2.userid = t1.userid
    AND t2.timestamp <= t1.timestamp) AS user_count
FROM myTable t1
```

I know you asked for a query w/o group by but here's one with it anyway :)

```
SELECT t1.userid, t1.timestamp, COUNT(*)
FROM myTable t1
JOIN myTable t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid AND t2.timestamp <= t1.timestamp
GROUP BY t1.userid, t1.timestamp
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a bunch. Will accept answer once SO lets me. Apparently I need to wait 4 mins.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a rank query also

```
SELECT  
userid,
`timestamp`,rank FROM(
SELECT 
  userid,
 `timestamp`,
@r:= CASE WHEN userid = @g THEN @r+1  ELSE @r:=1 END rank 
,@g:=userid
FROM t,(SELECT @r:=0,@g:=0) t1
ORDER BY userid,timestamp
) t
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26d1d/7)